# Let $a, b, c$ be positive integers such that $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Prove that $12$ divides $abc$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I already have the equations:

$a = xy, b = \frac{x^2-y^2}{2}, c = \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$

with $x > y \geq 1$

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/pythTripleDiv.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\text{gcd}(a,b,c)=1$, $a$ and $b$ cannot both be divisible by $3$. But if neither is divisible by $3$, then $c^2\equiv 2$ modulo $3$, which is impossible. Thus, exactly one of $a$ and $b$ is divisible by $3$.

Similarly, $a$ and $b$ cannot be both even. If they are both odd, then $c^2\equiv 2$ modulo $4$, which is impossible. Thus, exactly one of $a$ and $b$ is divisible by $2$. Say, $a$ is even. Then, $c$ is odd and $a^2=(c-b)(c+b)$. Because $b$ is odd, we infer that one number between $c-b$ and $c+b$ is divisible by $4$ whereas the other one is congruent to $2$ modulo $4$. In other words, $a^2$ is divisible by $8$ so $a$ must be divisible by $4$.

The claim now follows.

Answer (score 0):

Note first that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ gives you some features.

1. Taking $mod3$ on both sides, $c$ is divisible by $3$ iff both $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $3$. But that implies $gcd(a,b,c)=3m$ which is false. So $c$ is not divisible by 3. But then $c^2=1(mod3)$ obtainable only when either $a$ or $b$ is divisible by $3$. If both $a$ and $b$ are not divisible by $3$ then $a^2+b^2=2(mod3)$ which is a contradiction since $c^2$ cannot be $2(mod3)$, no perfect integral square is. So $3|abc$.
2. Take $(mod16)$ now. Note that squares give remainders $1,4,9,0(mod16)$. Also note that if a perfect square is divisible by 16, then the root is divisible by 4(why?).
   Since both $a$ and $b$ cannot be even, for then $c$ will be even, WLOG take $a$ even, then $a^2=0$ or $4(mod16)$. $b$ is odd, so $b^2=1$ or $9$ in this field. Taking $a^2=4$ gives $c^2=5$ or $13$ which is not possible. So whenever $a$ is even, $4|a$. Also if $a$ and $b$ are both odd, then $c^2=2$ or $10$ (no solution for a square).
   So, $4|ab$ and $12|abc$.